# Filter Piwik widget to only show data for current page

Tags: analytics, widgets, matomo

I am embedding a Piwik widget into my page so that when the widget is opened the end user can see page views for the specific page.

The issue I am having is that the widget shows analytics data from all across the whole site. My question is how can I filter the data to the widget so that only data for a specific page is used to generate the widget.